# MongoDB: Consolidating Arrays

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with around 1.1M documents. There is a fair amount of duplication in the collection, which I eventually will eliminate via a mapreduce. HOWEVER...

Here is a sample of redundant data:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("4ec6d3ac61910ad451f1eb7a"),
    "bii": 10.8105,
    "class": 2706,
    "decdeg": -48.8432,
    "lii": 286.488,
    "name": "HD 97312",
    "radeg": 167.8669,
    "vmag": 8.2,
    "xref": ["HD 97312"]
}

{
    "_id": ObjectId("4ec6d44c61910ad451f8b255"),
    "bii": 10.802,
    "class": 2900,
    "decdeg": -48.8517,
    "decpm": -0.008,
    "lii": 286.4896,
    "name": "PPM 316146",
    "radeg": 167.8644,
    "rapm": -0.0003,
    "vmag": 8.2,
    "xref": ["CPD -48 3792", "-48 6250", "HD 97312", "PPM 316146", "SAO 222629"]
}

{
    "_id": ObjectId("4ec6d48c61910ad451ff1ead"),
    "bii": 10.802,
    "class": 2700,
    "decdeg": -48.8517,
    "decpm": -0.013,
    "hd_component": 0,
    "lii": 286.4897,
    "name": "SAO 222629",
    "radeg": 167.8647,
    "rapm": -0.0006,
    "vmag": 8.3,
    "xref": ["CP-48 3792", "HD 97312", "SAO 222629"]
}
```

Since the xref array holds all of the cross references, I somehow need to combine these arrays into a single one with duplicates removed.

Can anyone suggest a "simple" way to do this so I don't have to write some sort of recursive js function?

Comment: At the end of the process do you want each of these three documents to contain `["CPD -48 3792", "-48 6250", "HD 97312", "PPM 316146", "SAO 222629"]` because they are all cross-referenced?  Or are you trying to build a list of all xrefs in all documents?  Please explain expected output.

Comment: You are correct. The end-result array should be the same for all of those cross-referenced documents.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% clear on what you need here. I see two possibilities here.

If you're doing a Map/Reduce, then you simply need to ensure duplicates when "reducing". Should be as simple as a couple of `for` loops in the M/R.

If you're building this data from scratch, then you should look at the `$addToSet` update function which will give you what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm not doing the map/reduce yet. Since Mongo doesn't support reducing to arrays (error is "reduce->multiple not supported"), I'm taking care of the array first. However, I'll look over the $addToSet, it looks promising at first glance.